# Finding element at x,y in a given matrix after rotation in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matrix, graph-theory

How can I find the element at index x,y in a given matrix after rotating the total matrix without performing the matrix rotation.

That means I am just interested in that coordinate don't want to perform total operation on total matrix and than simply get the element at any index.

```
Example:

suppose a matrix is given

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

and i want to find the element at 1,1 after rotating the matrix by 90 degree.

answer should be "7".

**NOTE**: Without performing the rotation on total matrix.

and if i want the element at 1,2 than the answer should be "4".

I hope I clearly communicated the question please help if you know the solution or algorithm for this question. 
Thank you.
```

Comment: so you want the the function that finds the element to perform the rotation? or just a function that calculates where one element will go?
either way at some point you need to calculate the rotation

Comment: also element 1,1 would be 5, element 0,0 would be 7, indexing starts at 0 not 1

Comment: Rotate the coordinates in the opposite direction that the matrix would be rotated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a `m x n matrix` and you are interested in the position of `M[i][j]` after rotation.

So, after a rotation of 90 degrees clockwise, `M[i][j] -> M[j][m+1-i].`
As in your example, `M[3][1] will be M[1][3+1-3] after rotation.`

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That's correct for OP's 1-based indices. For 0-based indices M[i][j] -> M[j][m-i].

Comment: I am interested in finding the element at M[i][j] after rotation. And I am able to find it now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map:

```
(x,y) -> (x', y')
```

Assume following:<sup>1</sup>

```
x' = ax + by + c
y' = dx + ey + f
```

Now, (1, 1) maps to (W, 1)<sup>2</sup>

```
w = a + b + c
1 = d + e + f
```

(1, W) maps to (1, 1)<sup>3</sup>

```
1 = a + bw + c
1 = d + ew + f
```

and (W, H) maps to (1, H)<sup>4</sup>

```
1 = aw + bh + c
h = dw = eH + f
```

Solve 2, 3 and 4 equation and fill in to 1 get the value. (Hint: b = -1, e = 0)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve the problem (other than using somebody else's solution).

It's fairly clear that the column index of each element is the row index of that element after rotation (at least, I hope that's clear).

So, the problem is the column index of an element after rotation.

The first row will become the last column, the second will be the second last, and so on until the last row which becomes the first column.

One way of viewing this is that we have the sequence (of rows) `i = 1, 2, ..., m` and want to map that to the sequence (of columns) `j = m, m - 1, m - 2, ..., 2, 1`.
But `m = m + 1 - 1`, `m - 1 = m + 1 - 2`, `m - 2 = m + 1 - 3`, ..., `1 = m + 1 - m`.
So the desired sequence is `j = m + 1 - i`.

In other words, `M[i][j] -> M[j][m + 1 - i]`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the explanation. I definitely accept your answer if I have the authority of accepting multiple answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For 90 degree rotation using correct indexing for x and y (starting at 0 not 1)
// Assuming square matrix

template<class T, int size>
T elemAfter90degRot(int x, int y, T[size][size] mat) {
    int j = y;
    int i = size - 1 - x;
    return mat[i][j];
}
```

I think that should do the trick for a 90 degree rotation of a square matrix

Comment: I think there is a mistake here and `i` and `j` are swapped.